# Send nodejs variable to ejs template with post request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I use Express JS in my nodejs application to create a post request.

IN **INDEX.JS** FILE I HAVE

```
this.app.post('/profile', (req, res, next) => {                        
            let password = req.body.password;            
            let newWallet = operator.createWalletFromPassword(password);
            let projectedWallet = projectWallet(newWallet);

            res.locals.projectedWallet =  projectedWallet
            res.render('profile.ejs', {
                user : req.user,
            });
            console.log(JSON.stringify(projectedWallet));        
        });
```

And in profile.ejs I have

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Node Authentication</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/httpServer/index.js" />
    <style>
        body        { padding-top:80px; word-wrap:break-word; }
    </style>
</head>
<br>
   <%- include header %>

   <div class="container">

    <div class="page-header text-center">
        <h1><span class="fa fa-anchor"></span> Profile Page</h1>
        <a href="/logout" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Logout</a>

    </div>
    <div class="row">

        <!-- LOCAL INFORMATION -->
        <div class="col-sm-6">

            <div class="well">
                <h3><span class="fa fa-user"></span> Local</h3>
                    <form action="/profile" method="post">
                        <p>                                                    
                            <strong>id</strong>: <%= user.id %><br>
                            <strong>username</strong>: <%= user.username %><br>
                            <strong>password</strong>: <%= user.password %>

                        </p>    

                        <textarea id="myTextArea" cols="50" rows="10" style="margin: 0px; width: 522px; height: 111px;">
                        <%=projectedWallet %>
                        </textarea>
                        <!-- these fields will be sent to server -->
                        <input type="hidden" name="username" value="<%= user.username %>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="password" value="<%= user.password %>">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" >Wallet</button>
                    </form>


            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
    <%- include footer %>
```

What I want is that, when I click the button in `profile.ejs`, the post request will work and do some function for me. After that, the result of function will be stored in `projectedWallet` variable. When I pass this `projectedWallet` to ejs file - in this case `profile.ejs` - it will show up in value of textarea. So, I want to make this variable to be accessed everywhere so I set

```
res.locals.projectedWallet =  projectedWallet
```

But even with this, it still does not work. When I click button in profile.ejs, it return an error `projectedWallet` is not defined. I really don't know what to do next?!

Do I have to include this node js file (`index.js`) into ejs template in head tag?

Version of Express JS that i use is version 4.

Comment: add projectedWallet in Index.js `res.render('profile.ejs', {
                user : req.user, projectedWallet
            });`

Comment: it still return "projectedWallet is not defined" in profile.ejs

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `projectedWallet` variable in `res.render`

```
 res.render('profile.ejs', { 
     user : req.user, 
     projectedWallet: projectedWallet });
```

Comment: it still return "projectedWallet is not defined" in profile.ejs. I already did every way but still return an error.

Comment: Does this error occur when you first load profile.ejs or after you send the post request?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can  the projectedWallet variable in res.render

   ```
   res.render('index', {projectedWallet:projectedWallet}, function(err, html) {
           console.log(html);
           res.send('done');
       })
   ```

   2. Second option will be to use session and accessing the sesssion variable

      var session = require('express-session');

      req.session.projectedWallet=projectedWallet;

Comment: So that you mean this is 2 options separately? Right?

Comment: even that, none of 2 option return success result.